# Disabled input is affecting the wrapper div and onClick event isn't working on div on Firefox browser

Tags: reactjs, firefox, input, onclick, disable

```html
func() {
      console.log('this func is working');
    }
    render() {
      <div onClick={this.func()}
        <input disabled="true" />
      <div>
    }
```

It is a reactJs project. My code is something like you see above. When the input is disabled I have a react-toastify notification on onClick event on the div because input is not clickable since it is disabled. But onClick event is not working on Firefox and MS Edge browsers. I don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

You evaluate `this.func()` then pass the result (`udnefined`) as the callback to `onClick`, thus triggering the function `undefined` upon clicking, and not having any effect.

What you should do instead, is pass a callback to your `onClick` attribute:

```
<div onClick={this.func}>
```

Comment: This answer should be excepted!

Answer (score 0):

See @Nino Filiu 's answer!

You have a bug in the code, just change to:

```html
func() {
  console.log('this func is working');
}
render() {
  <div onClick={this.func}>
    <input disabled="true" />
  </div>
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: @NinoFiliu just `>` and `/`